# Not able to download file from Google Drive with Postman

Tags: google-drive-api, postman

I want to use Google Drive from Postman, and when I tried to hit the API I am geting an error.

URL:

[`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1Iwvqcx073GhEU9eRD4vPihXoj2AV63LEyLZwu6i0jTQ?alt=media`](https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1Iwvqcx073GhEU9eRD4vPihXoj2AV63LEyLZwu6i0jTQ?alt=media)

I am getting:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "fileNotDownloadable",
        "message": "Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Google Docs files.",
        "locationType": "parameter",
        "location": "alt"
      }enter code here
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Google Docs files."
  }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provide more details. What type of file are you downloading? Could you post a sample of the request (like a screenshot of your Postman)?

Comment: url : https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1Iwvqcx073GhEU9eRD4vPihXoj2AV63LEyLZwu6i0jTQ?alt=media
and Header  Authorization token
this file is pdf

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `responseType: 'blob'` if you are trying to get a pdf file

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data
Check this link for more info on how to handle file content download